# Is QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren ever called on a heap object if it's not parented?

Tags: qt

Consider any QObject that is instantiated on the heap.  If it isn't parented, and nothing ever calls delete on it, should it ever for any reason enter `QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren()`?

Answer (score 0):

But of course, deletion is orthogonal to destruction. If that object is ever destructed, it will of course delete its children. Something may well call the destructor on the object without deallocating it from the heap. That'd be your code, or the code generated by the compiler, by the way, there's no "magic" in Qt to randomly destruct `QObject`s.

If the object's lifetime is managed by a suitable smart pointer (say `QScopedPointer`, `QSharedPointer`, `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::shared_ptr`), then the smart pointer will destruct the object, without you having explicitly to do anything.

Comment: Yes I realize there's no magic in Qt, it's just a well defined framework. I've seen stack traces that begin in deleteChildren of an object that is neither parented nor has delete called on it. This confuses me as to how execution could have ever entered the deleteChildren. I know that this shouldn't occur unless the object is explicitly given a parent or the object is manually deleted (in the case of it being a heap object).

Comment: If such object's instance was created as an automatic variable or a static variable, then compiler will destruct it. Again, it's not about deletion, it's about *destruction*. Two **very** different things.

Comment: Deletion happens to call the virtual destructor. That's a nice coincidence :) But the work is done within the destructor, so you should focus on what might be *destructing* your object, not deleting it.

Comment: Are you referring to a stack variable when you say automatic variable?  I'm talking about an object allocated on the heap with new, though it's a singleton and so it's static.  Log statements in its own destructor never show.  This object is a direct descendant of QObject.

Comment: @JoeyCarson: Yes, I meant a stack variable. What you describe is strange. Can you reproduce the code in a minimal test case that would have, perhaps, a couple dozen lines? It'd help immensely in tracking it down.